# simple MP3 player with folders

Tags: software-recommendation, folders, mp3, mediaplayer

I've been using SoundJam MP since it came out and many years ago I found a beta version that worked on OS X and that's the reason I can still use it.

Unfortunately, with OS X Lion, PPC support is gone and I need to find a similar app for my music listening.

My main objective is to find a software that allows me to add folders with MP3s and allows me to sort it manually and even sort the files inside the folder, instead of (as iTunes and others do) having the app sort it by album/artist, because I have several MP3s that aren't even tagged and I want to control it and not let the app sort and "mix" (wrongly) for me.

I've searched a lot and tried so many apps already without success (ex: cog, instinctiv, neutrino, songbird, vox).

Anyone knows of such a software?

P.S. the app can be either free or paid (reasonably priced).

Comment: maybe could you emphasize, in regards to your main objective, why the apps you tried didn't satisy you. I think Vox rely on a manually managed playlist, and doesn't sort by album/artist, so what is missing in it ?

Comment: @kraymer I haven't found a way to do that with Vox. I can't find any playlist with that App. Being able to add folders and place whatever I want (MP3s) in them is my main need. What most apps do is to (if folders exist) organize them according to their tags, I just don't wan't that and also can't rely on tagging.

Comment: iTunes can allow for manual sorting of the iTunes folder if it's such a big deal to you..

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX sorting multiple files is inpractical and far from the topic of my question. Also, iTunes is incredibly inadequate when dealing with untagged files, you have a poor way to organize them, ence my request, I just need an app to accept and use folders and keep the files in those folders.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use iTunes or Songbird? Both are great applications.

Comment: @daviesgeek did you even read my question? do iTunes or Songbird allow you to organize at will any MP3 in their folder and not have them all in a bunch? I can't rely on tags since I'm dealing with my own recordings, and such a "simple" task of having folders to organize your music isn't present in any of those two apps :(

Comment: @Jack I did read your question. Why do you organize MP3s in a folder? Not to be rude, but I really don't see the usefulness of organizing MP3s in a folder.

Comment: @daviesgeek because that's one way to keep them organized. Otherwise they will end up in the "pile" and organized either by name or whatever, I just needed the hability to have folfers. Think of OS X without folders, that's how I see iTunes, do you see the usefulness of having folders? I would like an app that could keep the folder and the tracks as they are, don't mind having them organized by filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I'm maybe not fully understand the question, but [the VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) cannot do the job?

You can drag into the playlist window any music files (in fact any multimedia files), can rearrange them manually and so on..

so use the VLC as a music player and not as a video-player.

Comment: It does the same as any other, if you drop many folders there, it ignores the folders and "spits" out the MP3 organized by tags, and as I said I can't (and don't want to) rely on tags. Both Audion and SoundJam could do this *so simple* task, drag a folder from the finder and the folder is kept, you could move it, drag/delete files.

Comment: besides the interface of vlc for mac at this time is not precisely nice (you cannot add new columns for ordering your music like in the windows version)

Comment: I don't know how I missed it the time I commented on your answer, but today I had to use VLC and noticed it did exactly what I wanted and what you described! thanks!